# Symfony 2.1 twig form_errors contains not all errors

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

```
form_errors(form)
```

It contains just part of form errors. Some fields render their form errors along with them. There are about 14 errors and form_errors contains only 7 of them.

Id don't get how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

With so little information to go on, I can only guess that it might be a problem with error bubbling for the individual fields.

Make sure that you set the error_bubbling parameter to true so that the error gets attached to the form:

```
'error_bubbling'=>true
```

Otherwise, you probably have errors attached for the fields in question, to the individual fields, and not to the form, again assuming that is the behavior you want.